# Why is Hibernate including an identity field with inserts?

Tags: java, hibernate

The model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CSU_AUDIT")
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllEventsForObjectId", query = "from AuditEvent e where e.objectId = :objectId order by e.auditTimestamp desc")
public class AuditEvent implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 577051869176721340L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int auditId;

    @Column(name = "INSERT_TS")
    private Date auditTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    private String objectId;

    @Column(name = "ACTION_CODE")
    private String actionCode;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "FIELD_NAME")
    private String fieldName;

    @Column(name = "OLD_VALUE")
    private String oldValue;

    @Column(name = "NEW_VALUE")
    private String newValue;
```

The simple DAO method:

```
public void insertEvent(AuditEvent event) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        log.info("Saving audit event...");
        log.debug(event);
        session.save(event);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

The session factory is managed by Spring's `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`.

Relevant exception info (more available, if necessary):

```
2012-07-12 09:01:41,049 DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - executing identity-insert immediately
2012-07-12 09:01:41,053 DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2012-07-12 09:01:41,066 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into CSU_AUDIT (auditId, ACTION_CODE, INSERT_TS, FIELD_NAME, NEW_VALUE, OBJECT_ID, OLD_VALUE, USER_ID) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2012-07-12 09:01:41,100 DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2012-07-12 09:01:41,117 DEBUG org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - could not insert: [com.cinfin.ecm.csudocmgr.audit.AuditEvent] [insert into CSU_AUDIT (auditId, ACTION_CODE, INSERT_TS, FIELD_NAME, NEW_VALUE, OBJECT_ID, OLD_VALUE, USER_ID) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -206, SQLSTATE: 42703, SQLERRMC: AUDITID
```

I don't understand why the field annotated as `@ID` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` is being included in the insert. Everything I've read indicated that hibernate should omit this field entirely. On the database side this field is to be generated as identity, though I don't have the generation code to know for sure how it has been declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see in the logs, it passes `default` as the value for the generated column, which means: use the default value for this column. [DB2's documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000970.htm) says:

> DEFAULT
>
> Specifies that the default value is to be used. The result of specifying DEFAULT depends on how the column was defined, as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the IDENTITY clause is used, the value is generated by the database manager.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Although I've never used DB2 and can't decipher the cryptic error message.